# Unable to find a column which is displayed in the Custom List

Tags: list, column

I have a custom list in which one column named "Status" (A look up field which is referenced in this list). is displayed with out any data.

However, if I go to the menu option "Settings -> Document Library Settings", I couldn't see the field "Status" that is displayed in the custom list.

I have attached the screenshot below for your reference.

[image: Custom List]

[image: Document library Settings]

Please let me know how I can re-reference it.

**Note: I am using SharePoint 2007**

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using a content type on this library.

It looks like the content type you are using created some columns with the attribute of "SEALED" set to "TRUE". This just means that they can not be edited through the browser or object model.

The only way I see to remove something like this is by removing the related content type and using a tool like SharePoint Manager (http://spm.codeplex.com/) to manually delete the field from the list.